# block libwww-perl on windows server 2003

Tags: htaccess, iis

Could anyone tell me how to block access to a website for "libwww-perl" agents.

Can only seem to find .htaccess solutions.

Many thanks

john

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this site you can do blocking on iis after installing the "URL Rewrite Module" http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/blocking-bots-based-on-useragent
The specific pattern you would want to use is `libwww-perl`

Here is an almost identical question asked on serverfault https://serverfault.com/questions/408913/can-iis-block-specific-user-agent-from-requesting-a-page-web It suggests installing "Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter" or "Microsoft URLScan"